# IOS: Touch outside layer mask but inside frame

Tags: ios, uiview, mask

I have an **UIView** with a layermask (smaller than its frame) that can receive touches. 
Now the thing is that i want to restrict those touches within the layer mask.

The mask is a rendered shape and not always a rectangle.

Do i have to do this with:

```
pointInside:withEvent:
```

or

```
hitTest:withEvent:
```

Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating a method that checks if there a solid or transparant pixel in the layer at a specific position:

```
- (BOOL)isSolidPixel:(CGImageRef)image withXPosition:(int)xPos andYPosition:(int)yPos {
    if(xPos > CGImageGetWidth(image) || yPos > CGImageGetHeight(image))
        return NO;

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image));
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    int pixelInfo = yPos * CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image) + xPos * 4;

    UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo];

    CFRelease(pixelData);

    if (alpha) 
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Its bit old question but maybe it would be useful for someone :)

At your views .h file;

```
@interface CustomPhotoFrame : UIView {
  @protected
    CGPathRef borderPath;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPathRef borderPath;
```

And, at your .m file;

```
@synthesize borderPath;

- (void)setClippingPath:(CGPathRef)path 
{
    CGPathRelease(borderPath);
    borderPath = path;
    CGPathRetain(borderPath);
}  

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGPathContainsPoint(borderPath, NULL, point, FALSE);
}
```

At you drawrect method; call;

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// your path codes.. assume that its a circle;

aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(centeredCircleRect)];

CGPathRef cgPath = CGPathCreateCopy(aPath.CGPath);
[self setClippingPath:cgPath];
```

Now your touch method only detects if your touch is in circle masked view.